# Issues with Internet speed in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: networking, drivers, internet

I connect to the Internet via WiFi with a D-Link DWA-582 Network-adapter on Ubuntu 19.04 dual-booted with Windows 8.1. I'm using Ubuntu actively since March of this year and never had any serious problems. Since some time has passed, the Internet speed on my Ubuntu distribution has gone down significantly for unknown reasons. Windows is unaffected by this. I feel lucky if I get 2MB/s but that has become rather rare. The average speed is about 700-900kB/s.

I tried several things out to solve this issue, but nothing seemed to work. I disabled IPv6, but no improvement. I tried installing drivers from the rtlwifi repo from GitHub, but the speed still didn't go up. I googled myself half to death to find a solution but nothing worked so far.

I don't know if my networkcard is to blame because in Windows the speed is as it should be (about 8MB/s) but I tried another external adapter (TP-Link AC1200 T4UH) in Ubuntu and, strangely enough, the speed was suddenly in the normal range.

I took another speedtest on a Live-USB distribution of 19.04 to see if I might have installed some software on my normal system that slowed the Internet connection down but sadly I have gotten the same slow results.

Does Ubuntu have some problems with the DWA-582 in general or is it just me? Am I not using the correct drivers? I really don't get it.

The current driver is rtl8821ae.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you confirm if the speed has dropped over time, or has it been low since you started using ubuntu.  It does sound like a driver issue, but don't know enough to say if you need different driver or just need to enable older driver.

Comment: Google around some and found this.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/7vecvb/dlink_dwa582_ac1200_internet_speed_drops_down_in/

Comment: Do you have QoS enabled in your router? Do you use a VPN?

Comment: What's your `MTU`? Should be set by the WiFi router to 1492, not 1500, but you can set it with `ip link set ...` see `man ip-link`

Comment: To answer your questions: the drop in speed occured about two months ago and has been steadingly decresing further. I don't have QoS enabled and I don't use a VPN.

Interestingly enough, the bottom comment of the reddit post sent by @crip659 seemed to do the trick. I tried several variants of this method but the line ´git checkout extended´ probably was a small detail that was crucial. Now I got my full speed back. Can't really explain how, but I'm happy nonetheless. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @waltinator why do you say MTU should be 1492? That would be for DSL.